# apply XSL template dynamically . Template is in external xslt file and included into main xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have one main xslt which is `cdcatalog.xsl` and linked to xml file `cdcatalog.xml`.
I am trying to apply-templates dynamically based on the value in `country`. Some of the actual templates are external `.xsl` files.

**cdcatalog.xsl**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:include href="cdcatalog_in.xsl"/>
    <xsl:include href="cdcatalog_usa.xsl"/>
    <xsl:include href="cdcatalog_uk.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>  
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd">
     <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
    </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
    Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
     <br />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="artist">
    Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
   <br />
   </xsl:template>

   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**cdcatalog.xml** contents are as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
    <catalog>
     <cd>
       <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
       <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
       <country>USA</country>
       <company>Columbia</company>
       <price>10.90</price>
       <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
       <title>Hide your heart</title>
       <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
       <country>UK</country>
       <company>CBS Records</company>
       <price>9.90</price>
       <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
       <title>Greatest Hits</title>
       <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
       <country>USA</country>
       <company>RCA</company>
       <price>9.90</price>
       <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
       <title>Still got the blues</title>
       <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
       <country>IN</country>
       <company>Virgin records</company>
       <price>10.20</price>
       <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    </catalog>
```

**cdcatalog_in.xsl** content are as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="cd[country='IN']" name="IN" >
 <h4>Country: India</h4>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**cdcatalog_usa.xsl** content are as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="cd[country='USA']" name="USA" >
 <h4>Country: United States of America</h4>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**cdcatalog_uk.xsl** content are as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="cd[country='UK']" name="UK" >
 <h4>Country: United Kingdom</h4>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected Output**

```
Title : Empire Burlesque
Artist: Bob Dylan
Country: United States of America

Title : Hide your heart
Artist: Bonnie Tyler
Country: United Kingdom

Title : Greatest Hits
Artist: Dolly Parton
Country: United States of America

Title : Still got the blues
Artist: Gary Moore
Country: India
```

**Getting below output which is incorrect**

```
My CD Collection

Country: United States of America 2

Country: United Kingdom

Country: United States of America 2

Country: India
```

Thanks in Advance.
Srini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the opportunity to change the included xslt files? If so, you could change them to match on `country` instead of `cd`. For example the *cdcatalog_in.xsl* file would look like this:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="cd/country[.='IN']">
     <h4>Country: India</h4>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then, in your main XSLT file, the template matching `cd` would look like this

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
 <p>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="country"/>  
   <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>  
   <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
</p>
</xsl:template>
```

You could even add a template matching just matching `country` in the main XSLT too, to capture "unknown" cases

```
<xsl:template match="country">
    <h4>Country: UNKOWN</h4>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good to handle unknown country case

Comment: Instead of showing `UNKNOWN` when respective template is missing, probably the same country code can be shown?

Comment: this solution is working fine. Also we are still in design phase so we can make changes to external templates.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**: you have two templates matching the same node and you need to apply both.

**Solution**: Instead of **including** the external stylesheets, **import** them. Then use `xsl:apply-imports` within the local template to apply the imported one.

**No modification of the external styleshets is necessary.**

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:import href="cdcatalog_in.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="cdcatalog_usa.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="cdcatalog_uk.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2>  
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-imports />  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
     <br />
   </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
    Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
   <br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Alernatively, you could use **modes** - but still without modifying the external stylesheets:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:include href="cdcatalog_in.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="cdcatalog_usa.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="cdcatalog_uk.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2>  
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="first"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd" mode="first" >
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
     <br />
   </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
    Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
   <br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This solution is working. will there be any performance issue bcz apply-templates select="." as we are not addressing exact template. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @SriniRao I am not sure what you mean by "*not addressing exact template*".  Applying templates to the current node is no different than applying templates to any other node/s.  If there will be performance issues, they are much more likely to be caused by having multiple files, one for each country, than anything else.

Comment: Instead of apply-templates select="." Is there any possibility to apply-template select="name" So that the system will pull directly that template.

Comment: I am afraid I still don't know what you mean, or what the problem here is.

Answer (score 1):

Modes can be useful here. Change your included template rules to be like:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="cd[country='IN']" mode="country-name">
     <h4>Country: India</h4>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

and change the generic template rule to:

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="country-name"/>
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: But actually, if the issue is really just expanding country codes to country names, I would use a lookup document that defines the mapping from codes to names, rather than building it into code.

Answer (score -1):

In stead of using multiple xsl files for each count, all the `cd` elements can be  done in single xsl using template.

*Here is the modified single style sheet:* **cdcatalog.xsl**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <p>
            Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
            <xsl:value-of select="./title"/></span><br/>
            Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
            <xsl:value-of select="./artist"/></span><br/>
            Country: <span style="color:#00ff11">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="./country = 'IN'">
                    India
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="./country = 'UK'">
                    United Kingdom
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="./country = 'USA'">
                    United States of America
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./country"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            </span><br/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Hope this works for your need.

Comment: The trouble about this approach is that it loses all the flexibility and reusability of the original, which is presumably attempting to make it much easier to change the list of countries that are recognized. Template rules are good for this kind of purpose; don't abandon them at the first sight of difficulty.

Comment: Thank you for input @MichaelKay. It wasn't meant to abandon the difficulty, just could not realize why many stylesheets used. Realized after posting my answer that multiple files can have flexibility to extend when a new country is introduced and was working the change with same way as user was looking for. Mean while I found your answer. Glad to know, and value your feedback. And thank you for the `mode` which I wasn't aware.